# Show child on parent hover instead of on parent OR child hover

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, hover, transition

I've created a simple dropdown menu that scales and fades in whenever I hover over the parent list item, "Services".  Everything works as it should except for when I hover over the child element (dropdown menu) which also makes it appear.  I understand that simply hiding it with opacity will not prevent a user from hovering over it but it allows for the 0.4s transition to take effect.  If I were to hide it with display:none or visibility:hidden, the transition becomes instant.  I'm considering using jQuery to solve this but was wondering if there is a solution based purely in CSS.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nolder/agznem7r/)

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Montserrat;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav {
  background-color: white;
  height: 60px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

nav > ul > li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  height: 60px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

nav a {
  color: rgba(165,175,185,1);
}

nav > ul > li > a {
  padding: 0 20px;
  height: 100%;
  line-height: 60px;
}

nav > ul > li:hover > a {
  color: rgba(105,115,125,1);
}

nav > ul > li:first-of-type {
  margin-right: auto;
}

.services-list-container {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  top: 100%;
  height: auto;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: rotateX(-20deg) scale(0.9,0.9);
 transform-origin: 0 0;
 transition: transform 0.4s ease, opacity 0.4s ease;
}

.services-list-container ul {
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 6px 16px rgba(40, 40, 90, 0.15);
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.services-list-container a {
  padding: 20px;
  display: block;
}

.services-list-container a:hover {
  padding: 20px;
  display: block;
  background-color: rgba(235,240,245,1);
}
  
.hover:hover .services-list-container {
  transform: rotateX(0deg) scale(1,1);
 opacity: 1;
 transition: transform 0.4s ease, opacity 0.4s ease;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">[Logo]</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">About</a>
    </li>
    <li class="hover">
      <a href="#">Services</a>
      <div class="services-list-container">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Information</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Technology</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Training</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Project Support</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">News</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Jobs</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not that you are hovering over the child element, it's that your list elements are so tall from the height:60px that when you hover under the words, it's still going over the li element.

Comment: Correct, I forgot to mention that.  However I tried rewriting it so that the submenu appears when hovering over the <a> element within the list item but to no success.  Is that because an element cannot affect its sibling on hover?

Comment: Oh and I see I was wrong about the height, for some reason I thought 60px was taller than that. Let me try a few things.

Answer (score 0):

If you are targeting supporting browsers you can use [pointer-events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events?v=control) to prevent the submenu from causing a hover mouse event

Give your element `pointer-events:none` to disable

```
.services-list-container {
  pointer-events:none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  top: 100%;
  height: auto;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: rotateX(-20deg) scale(0.9,0.9);
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  transition: transform 0.4s ease, opacity 0.4s ease;
}
```

Then to make sure you can still enter the submenu, reset `pointer-events` while your .hover elements are hovered

```
.hover:hover .services-list-container {
  pointer-events:all;
  transform: rotateX(0deg) scale(1,1);
  opacity: 1;
  transition: transform 0.4s ease, opacity 0.4s ease;
}
```

Demo

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Montserrat;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav {
  background-color: white;
  height: 60px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

nav > ul > li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  height: 60px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

nav a {
  color: rgba(165,175,185,1);
}

nav > ul > li > a {
  padding: 0 20px;
  height: 100%;
  line-height: 60px;
}

nav > ul > li:hover > a {
  color: rgba(105,115,125,1);
}

nav > ul > li:first-of-type {
  margin-right: auto;
}

.services-list-container {
  pointer-events:none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  top: 100%;
  height: auto;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: rotateX(-20deg) scale(0.9,0.9);
 transform-origin: 0 0;
 transition: transform 0.4s ease, opacity 0.4s ease;
}

.services-list-container ul {
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 6px 16px rgba(40, 40, 90, 0.15);
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.services-list-container a {
  padding: 20px;
  display: block;
}

.services-list-container a:hover {
  padding: 20px;
  display: block;
  background-color: rgba(235,240,245,1);
}
  
.hover:hover .services-list-container {
  pointer-events:all;
  transform: rotateX(0deg) scale(1,1);
 opacity: 1;
 transition: transform 0.4s ease, opacity 0.4s ease;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">[Logo]</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">About</a>
    </li>
    <li class="hover">
      <a href="#">Services</a>
      <div class="services-list-container">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Information</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Technology</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Training</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Project Support</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">News</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Jobs</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Interesting!  I didn't know there was such a property.  Although it works perfectly, unfortunately, I will need to cater to a lot more browsers than what currently supports it.  Thanks for the insight!

Answer (score 0):

A combination of visibility:hidden; with the opacity changes helps you to keep that animation while still preventing it from triggering outside of the intended menu area:

https://jsfiddle.net/4wg4sbqy/
CSS:

```
* {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      font-family: Montserrat;
    }

    li {
      list-style: none;
    }

    a {
      text-decoration: none;
    }

    nav {
      background-color: white;
      height: 60px;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
    }

    nav > ul > li {
      display: inline-block;
      position: relative;
      height: 60px;
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    nav a {
      color: rgba(165,175,185,1);
    }

    nav > ul > li > a {
      padding: 0 20px;
      height: 100%;
      line-height: 60px;
    }

    nav > ul > li:hover > a {
      color: rgba(105,115,125,1);
    }

    nav > ul > li:first-of-type {
      margin-right: auto;
    }

    .services-list-container {
      position: absolute;
      width: 200px;
      top: 100%;
      height: auto;
      opacity: 0;
      visibility: hidden;
      transform: rotateX(-20deg) scale(0.9,0.9);
        transform-origin: 0 0;
        transition: transform 0.4s ease, opacity 0.4s ease;
    }

    .services-list-container ul {

      background-color: white;
      box-shadow: 0 6px 16px rgba(40, 40, 90, 0.15);
      position: relative;
      margin-top: 30px;
    }

    .services-list-container a {
      padding: 20px;
      display: block;
    }

    .services-list-container a:hover {
      padding: 20px;
      display: block;
      background-color: rgba(235,240,245,1);
    }

    .hover:hover .services-list-container {
      visibility: visible;
      transform: rotateX(0deg) scale(1,1);
        opacity: 1;
        transition: transform 0.4s ease, opacity 0.4s ease;
    }
```

HTML:

```
   <nav>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">[Logo]</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">About</a>
    </li>
    <li class="hover">
      <a href="#">Services</a>
      <div class="services-list-container">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Information</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Technology</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Training</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Project Support</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">News</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Jobs</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: I tried that but the exit transition was still instantaneous which is strange.  Perhaps I had another error somewhere but I'm fairly certain I didn't.

Comment: @Nolder You're right that the exit transition still appears to be instantaneous. For the animation both ways I would probably go with jQuery in this case but if having the animation on just the initial dropdown or as a fallback is acceptable then it's an option for sure.

Answer (score -1):

Please check if this is what you want. Submenu is hidden until the hover takes place.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Montserrat;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav {
  background-color: white;
  height: 60px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

nav>ul>li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  height: 60px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

nav a {
  color: rgba(165, 175, 185, 1);
}

nav>ul>li>a {
  padding: 0 20px;
  line-height: 60px;
}

nav>ul>li:hover>a {
  color: rgba(105, 115, 125, 1);
}

nav>ul>li:hover .services-list-container  {
  display: inline-block;
}

nav>ul>li:first-of-type {
  margin-right: auto;
}

.services-list-container {
  visibility: hidden;
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  top: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .4s ease;
}

.services-list-container ul {
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 6px 16px rgba(40, 40, 90, 0.15);
  position: relative;
}

.services-list-container a {
  padding: 20px;
  display: block;
}

.services-list-container a:hover  {
  background-color: rgba(235, 240, 245, 1);
}

.hover:hover .services-list-container {
  z-index: 0;
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">[Logo]</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">About</a>
    </li>
    <li class="hover">
      <a href="#">Services</a>
      <div class="services-list-container">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Information</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Technology</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Training</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Project Support</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">News</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Jobs</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
```